# define list of map in application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I'm using spring boot framework, is it possible to define List of HashMap structure in appllication.properties file and use that List in my java classes. Here is the example structure in prorperties file.

```
prefix:
listProp1:
    - listValue1
    - listValue2
    - listValue3
listProp2:
    - listValue1
    - listValue2
    - listValue3
listProp3:
    - listValue1
    - listValue2
    - listValue3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON structure in properties file

```
myMap="{[{"mapKey1": "mapVal1","mapKey2": "mapVal2",},{"mapKey11": "mapVal11","mapKey21": "mapVal22",}]}"
```